# How can i use canvas and draw on it in a Windows Form Application? C#

Tags: c#, canvas

I would like to know how can i create a canvas in a Windows Form App and then draw on it. 
I know that canvas can be used in WPF. So is there any way i can use it in Windows Form App ? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at [Using Canvas in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716379/using-canvas-in-windows-form-net-application) and [Equivalent of Canvas in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117986/equivalent-of-canvas-in-windows-forms)

Comment: In WinForms everything is canvas. Start with `Control`.